# openbox: open new windows in specific locations

Tags: openbox

Is it possible to configure openbox that it opens new windows of specific apps in certain areas? For example app A should open in the upper left quadrant of the screen, app B in the lower left quadrant and app C on the right half of the screen. Or to at least set coordinates where the windows should be opened.

I guess that there are some things to write into the `rc.xml` but I have no clue what.

I'm running raspbian with lightdm & openbox if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go the `applications` section of your `rc.xml`. There is a whole commented section for what you can do, here a copy:

```
<!--
  # this is an example with comments through out. use these to make your
  # own rules, but without the comments of course.
  # you may use one or more of the name/class/role/title/type rules to specify
  # windows to match

  <application name="the window's _OB_APP_NAME property (see obxprop)"
              class="the window's _OB_APP_CLASS property (see obxprop)"
          groupname="the window's _OB_APP_GROUP_NAME property (see obxprop)"
         groupclass="the window's _OB_APP_GROUP_CLASS property (see obxprop)"
               role="the window's _OB_APP_ROLE property (see obxprop)"
              title="the window's _OB_APP_TITLE property (see obxprop)"
               type="the window's _OB_APP_TYPE property (see obxprob)..
                      (if unspecified, then it is 'dialog' for child windows)">
  # you may set only one of name/class/role/title/type, or you may use more
  # than one together to restrict your matches.

  # the name, class, role, and title use simple wildcard matching such as those
  # used by a shell. you can use * to match any characters and ? to match
  # any single character.

  # the type is one of: normal, dialog, splash, utility, menu, toolbar, dock,
  #    or desktop

  # when multiple rules match a window, they will all be applied, in the
  # order that they appear in this list


    # each rule element can be left out or set to 'default' to specify to not
    # change that attribute of the window

    <decor>yes</decor>
    # enable or disable window decorations

    <shade>no</shade>
    # make the window shaded when it appears, or not

    <position force="no">
      # the position is only used if both an x and y coordinate are provided
      # (and not set to 'default')
      # when force is "yes", then the window will be placed here even if it
      # says you want it placed elsewhere.  this is to override buggy
      # applications who refuse to behave
      <x>center</x>
      # a number like 50, or 'center' to center on screen. use a negative number
      # to start from the right (or bottom for <y>), ie -50 is 50 pixels from
      # the right edge (or bottom). use 'default' to specify using value
      # provided by the application, or chosen by openbox, instead.
      <y>200</y>
      <monitor>1</monitor>
      # specifies the monitor in a xinerama setup.
      # 1 is the first head, or 'mouse' for wherever the mouse is
    </position>

    <size>
      # the size to make the window.
      <width>20</width>
      # a number like 20, or 'default' to use the size given by the application.
      # you can use fractions such as 1/2 or percentages such as 75% in which
      # case the value is relative to the size of the monitor that the window
      # appears on.
      <height>30%</height>
    </size>

    <focus>yes</focus>
    # if the window should try be given focus when it appears. if this is set
    # to yes it doesn't guarantee the window will be given focus. some
    # restrictions may apply, but Openbox will try to

    <desktop>1</desktop>
    # 1 is the first desktop, 'all' for all desktops

    <layer>normal</layer>
    # 'above', 'normal', or 'below'

    <iconic>no</iconic>
    # make the window iconified when it appears, or not

    <skip_pager>no</skip_pager>
    # asks to not be shown in pagers

    <skip_taskbar>no</skip_taskbar>
    # asks to not be shown in taskbars. window cycling actions will also
    # skip past such windows

    <fullscreen>yes</fullscreen>
    # make the window in fullscreen mode when it appears

    <maximized>true</maximized>
    # 'Horizontal', 'Vertical' or boolean (yes/no)
  </application>

  # end of the example
-->
```

For this specific example the result would be:

```
  <!-- A -->
  <application name="A">
    <decor>yes</decor>
    <shade>no</shade>
    <position force="no">
      <!-- start pos at (0,0), top-left corner -->
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <monitor>1</monitor>
    </position>
    <size>
      <!-- go in height & width only 50%, one quarter of the screen -->
      <width>50%</width>
      <height>50%</height>
    </size>
    <focus>yes</focus>
    <desktop>1</desktop>
    <layer>normal</layer>
    <iconic>no</iconic>
  </application>

  <!-- B -->
  <application name="B">
    <decor>yes</decor>
    <shade>no</shade>
    <position force="no">
      <!-- start pos at (0,mid of screen), middle-left of screen -->
      <x>0</x>
      <y>50%</y>
      <monitor>1</monitor>
    </position>
    <size>
      <!-- go in height & width only 50%, one quarter of the screen -->
      <width>50%</width>
      <height>50%</height>
    </size>
    <focus>yes</focus>
    <desktop>1</desktop>
    <layer>normal</layer>
    <iconic>no</iconic>
  </application>
  
  <!-- C -->
  <application name="C">
    <decor>yes</decor>
    <shade>no</shade>
    <position force="no">
      <!-- start pos at (mid of screen, 0), top-mid of screen -->
      <x>50%</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <monitor>1</monitor>
    </position>
    <size>
      <!-- take up half the screen width, but all the height -->
      <width>50%</width>
      <height>100%</height>
    </size>
    <focus>yes</focus>
    <desktop>1</desktop>
    <layer>normal</layer>
    <iconic>no</iconic>
  </application>
```

to find the `_OB_APP_*` properties you can run `obxprop | grep _OB_APP` and then click the window for which you want the properties.